# Бот, который повторяет значение, введенное участником?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Пользователь вводит команду !аукцион и через пробле указывает время, допустим 12:20.
Далее бот должен вывести Аукцион: это значение времени - время+14ч. Как рассчитать +14ч все работает, но только от текущего момента. Т.е. если убрать самостоятельный ввод времени пользователем.
Необходимо же, чтоб пользователь сам вводил время.

Значение now не задано, в этом и проблема. Как его обозначить, чтобы бот понимал, что следующее слово за словом аукцион в команде будет означать введенное время, от которого начнется отсчет. Время вводится самостоятельно, не от текущего момента, оно может быть любым.

```
var time = new Date();
time.setHours(time.getHours() + 14);
timehours =time.getHours();
timeminutes = time.getMinutes();
if (timehours < 10) timehours = '0' + timehours;
if (timeminutes < 10) timeminutes = '0' + timepminutes;
var result = (timehours + ":" + timeminutes);

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
   if (message.author.bot) {
      return;
   }

   if (message.content === "!аукцион"  +  now) {  //now - это некое значение времени, введенное пользователем
      message.reply("Аукцион: " + now + " - " + result );
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы бот понимал, что следующее слово после "!аукцион" - это значение времени, необходимо извлечь это значение из сообщения пользователя.

Вы можете использовать метод split() для разделения строки сообщения на отдельные слова, и затем использовать второй элемент массива, содержащего эти слова, как значение времени.

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
   if (message.author.bot) {
      return;
   }

   const args = message.content.split(' ');
   if (args[0] === "!аукцион" && args[1]) {
      const userTime = args[1];
      const auctionTime = new Date(userTime);
      auctionTime.setHours(auctionTime.getHours() + 14);
      const timeHours = auctionTime.getHours();
      const timeMinutes = auctionTime.getMinutes();
      const result = `${timeHours}:${timeMinutes < 10 ? '0' + timeMinutes : timeMinutes}`;
      message.reply(`Аукцион: ${userTime} - ${result}`);
   }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, теперь понятно.